# Is it possible to hide tracked changes popups in Pages?

Tags: pages

When working in a Pages document that contains change-tracking content, popups like this will appear as you work in the document, whether or not tracking is currently turned on:

[image]

I find these very distracting, and I have not found a way to turn them off without accepting or rejecting all changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of annoying but it works.

In your document, in the menu bar, go to `View>Show Comments & Changes Pane` then under `View Options` select `Hide Changes`.

**Note**: You must keep this pane open or the popups will come back, although you can move it off screen or shrink it to a minimal size.

[image]

[image]

If you would also like to hide the coloring you can Select the Gear icon  [image] and then select `Final`

[image]